# Sort CSV by column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sorting

I need to sort a CSV table by the column name. The data I get in CSV has various number of columns, but the column name is static. This is the data I have:

```
X,Blue,Black,Red,Green,Total
Thomas,2,0,0,0,2
Andy,0,1,0,0,1
Luise,0,0,2,1,3
Mark,1,0,0,1,2
Ronda,0,1,0,1,2
```

Pretty print:

```
  X     Blue    Black   Red Green  Total
Thomas   2       0       0    0     2
Andy     0       1       0    0     1
Luise    0       0       2    1     3
Mark     1       0       0    1     2
Ronda    0       1       0    1     2
```

Normally I could just sort by `row[5]` but if I get a table without any Greens, or a table with additional column - Yellow, it will no longer work.

Therefore the question is, how can I sort this CSV file by the column named `Total`?

Can only use core python modules, no pandas. :(

Comment: `Can only use python modules, no pandas. :(`? Why? Is this homework?

Comment: pandas is python module

Comment: You have the column names somewhere, right? Look up the index of the one called `Total` and sort by that index.

Comment: What output do you want?  Printed or written to a file?

Comment: Is `Total` always the last column?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It's for work. Multiple users will use the script and they will only have the basic installation, don't want them to download a bulky library just for this.

Comment: @tripleee yes it is.

Comment: Then just `sort(key lambda row: row[-1])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to sort using a column name, it would be best to read your file using a Python [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) object as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    data = sorted(csv_input, key=lambda row: (row['Total'], row['X']))

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:    
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=csv_input.fieldnames)
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(data)
```

This would then allow you to sort based on the `Total` column regardless of where it is. The `csv.DictReader()` reads each row as a dictionary, using the first row as a header. The header values can then be used as dictionary keys to access items rather than using positional values with a normal `csv.reader()`. So your first data row would be read as:

```
{'Total': '1', 'Blue': '0', 'Black': '1', 'Green': '0', 'X': 'Andy', 'Red': '0'}
```

`csv_input` can then be passed directly to `sorted()` to create a sorted list of row dictionaries. The `key` is the `total` field and then also the `X` field for the cases where the total is the same.

This would then write a sorted `output.csv` as follows:

```
X,Blue,Black,Red,Green,Total
Andy,0,1,0,0,1
Mark,1,0,0,1,2
Ronda,0,1,0,1,2
Thomas,2,0,0,0,2
Luise,0,0,2,1,3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this,

```
reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv'))

header = reader.next()
sort_col_idx = header.index('Total')
sorted(reader, key=lambda row: row[sort_col_idx]) # Without header
[header] + sorted(reader, key=lambda row: row[sort_col_idx]) # With headers.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to sort according to any column.

```
import csv
import operator

data = csv.reader(open('input.csv'))

# function to sort according to any column.
# table corresponds to data and col is argument for the row number. here 5
def sort_table(table, col=0):
     return sorted(table, key=operator.itemgetter(col))

print(sort_table(data, 5))
```

However pandas are better option. Try getting used to that.

Comment: I'm afraid that wont do, as the number of columns is dynamic, so ``Total`` will not always have that index.